# Mongo remote connection problems

Tags: mongodb

I have a problem concerning remote connection to mongo server

bind_ip set to `0.0.0.0`

firewall ports 27017 and 28017 open

netstat -A shows listening to both

and yet no connection can be established, any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: Can you telnet to port 27017?

Comment: Can you post your error message? Thanks

Comment: Can you check with tcpdump ? `tcpdump port not ssh` so will not see ssh traffic

Answer (score 0):

MongoDb 3.4

Go to "cmd" command prompt and follow these steps:

1. `cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin`
2. `mongod --bind_ip 192.168.0.10`

   "192.168.0.10"  Type required ip

   [image]